# Creating dictionary from list of lists and obtain the maximum keys in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary from a list of lists. I create an example to something similar I am working on, which goes like this:

```
lst1 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','a'],['g','b','i']]
lst2 = [[1,8,2],[4,3,6],[7,9,0]]
```

I tried something like this

```
mydict = [dict(zip(keys,values)) for keys in lst1 for values in lst2]

print (mydict) 
# Prints like this below 
#[{'a': 1, 'b': 8, 'c': 2}, {'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'c': 6}, {'a': 7, 'b': 9, 'c': 0}, {'d': 1, 'e': 8, 'a': 2}, {'d': 4, 'e': 3, 'a': 6}, {'d': 7, 'e': 9, 'a': 0}, {'g': 1, 'b': 8, 'i': 2}, {'g': 4, 'b': 3, 'i': 6}, {'g': 7, 'b': 9, 'i': 0}]
```

I could see the mistake i am doing is iterating `lst2` inside the `lst1` loop so the keys and values are assigned multiple times. But I need an output some thing like this

```
{{'a': 1, 'b': 8, 'c': 2}, {'d': 4, 'e': 3, 'a': 6}, {'g': 7, 'b': 9, 'i': 0}}
```

I want to preserve the structure of the list and create a keys and values for a dictionary, with which i could obtain the max key of the dictionaries. **So my ultimate goal is to obtain this**

```
"""
In the mydict 
{{'a': 1, 'b': 8, 'c': 2}, 
 {'d': 4, 'e': 3, 'a': 6}, 
 {'g': 7, 'b': 9, 'i': 0}}

the key 'b' has max_value of 8,
the key 'a' has max_value of 6,
the key 'b' has max_value of 9.

#the output i need is  [['b'],['a'],['b']]
"""
```

**EDITED:**

Thanks everyone for your answers, The iteration stops once its finds the max value how to get the keys of all with maximum values. For Eg:

```
lst1 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','a'],['g','b','i']]
lst2 = [[1,8,2],[4,3,6],[7,9,9]]
```

needs output as

```
[['b'], ['a'], ['b','i']]
```

Comment: Why is `max_mydict` a *list of lists*?

Comment: Why are you creating dictionaries to find `max_mydict`?

Comment: Sorry that was typed mistakenly, I want max_mydict which looks like that. Corrected it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update means you will need to use a loop for efficiency, e.g.:

```
In []:
r = []
for xs, ys in zip(lst1, lst2):
    m = max(ys)
    r.append([x for x, y in zip(xs, ys) if y == m])
r

Out[]:
[['b'], ['a'], ['b', 'i']]
```

Here's the inefficient (multiple calls to `max()`) comprehension version:

```
In []:
[[x for x, y in zip(xs, ys) if y == max(ys)] for xs, ys in zip(lst1, lst2)]

Out[]:
[['b'], ['a'], ['b', 'i']]
```

If you were really looking to create a `dict` then I would reverse the relationship and have the number as the key, e.g.:

```
In []:
r = []
for xs, ys in zip(lst1, lst2):
    d = {}
    for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
        d.setdefault(y, []).append(x)
    r.append(d)
r

Out[]:
[{1: ['a'], 2: ['c'], 8: ['b']}, {3: ['e'], 4: ['d'], 6: ['a']}, {7: ['g'], 9: ['b', 'i']}]
```

Then to get the maximums:

```
In []:
[d[max(d)] for d in r]

Out[]:
[['b'], ['a'], ['b', 'i']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, works great. There is a missing  Parentheses in the end at the fifth line of your first code, which showed up an error.

Answer (score 3):

To generate the dictionaries you could use

```
>>> [dict(z) for z in map(zip, lst1, lst2)]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 8, 'c': 2}, {'d': 4, 'e': 3, 'a': 6}, {'g': 7, 'b': 9, 'i': 0}]
```

Though, you don't have to create `dict` objects if you just need the letters corresponding to maximum values:

```
>>> [max(z)[1] for z in map(zip, lst2, lst1)]
['b', 'a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the `max_mydict` without an intermediate dictionary using `zip`.

This basically find the index of max item in each sublist in `list2` and then fetches the corresponding value from `list1`.

```
>>> [a[max(range(len(b)), key=b.__getitem__)] for a, b in zip(lst1, lst2)]
['b', 'a', 'b']
```

In two steps:

```
>>> indices = (max(range(len(x)), key=x.__getitem__) for x in lst2)
>>> [x[next(indices)] for x in lst1]
['b', 'a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following list comprehension. *Zipping* a second time the pair-wise lists from the first `zip` and calling `dict` on those:

```
l = [dict(zip(x, y)) for x, y in zip(lst1, lst2)]
print l
# [{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 8}, {'a': 6, 'e': 3, 'd': 4}, {'i': 0, 'b': 9, 'g': 7}]
```

And you can generate the max with:

```
print  [[max(d, key=d.get)] for d in l]
# [['b'], ['a'], ['b']]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
lst1 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','a'],['g','b','i']]
lst2 = [[1,8,2],[4,3,6],[7,9,0]]

final = [{c:d for c, d in zip(a, b)} for a, b in zip(lst1, lst2))]
```